Write value to data range that has been called previously
I have the following script:
function send_purchase_invoices() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");
  var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("purchase_invoices");

  var data_range = srcSheet.getRange('DK4:DR18'); 
  var data_data = data_range.getValues();
  var data_clean  = data_data.filter(function (r) {return !r[0]});

  var lr = dstSheet.getLastRow(); 

  dstSheet.getRange(lr+1, 1,data_clean.length,8).setValues(data_clean);  
  srcSheet.getRange(data_clean).setValues('SUBMITTED');
}

This line here:
srcSheet.getRange(data_clean).setValues('SUBMITTED');

I'm trying to call the data range set in this section:
  var data_range = srcSheet.getRange('DK4:DR18'); 
  var data_data = data_range.getValues();
  var data_clean  = data_data.filter(function (r) {return !r[0]});

Or, more specifically, column [0] as defined here:
 var data_clean  = data_data.filter(function (r) {return !r[0]});

So that it populates the word "SUBMITTED" to those cells.
Any constructive advice, greatly appreciated.

What should be in the rest of the cells of data_range?

Nothing. I am only looking to have column DK populated, as defined by whether [0] didn't have a value in it. After the script is run, those that didn't, and that were called, should have the word 'submitted' added.

I believe your goal is as follows.

You want to put a value SUBMITTED into the cells of column "DK" when the value of column "DK" is empty.

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
function send_purchase_invoices() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");
  var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("purchase_invoices");

  var data_range = srcSheet.getRange('DK4:DR18');
  var data_data = data_range.getValues();
  var data_clean = data_data.filter(function (r) { return !r[0] });

  var lr = dstSheet.getLastRow();


  // I modified the below script.
  if (data_clean.length == 0) return;
  dstSheet.getRange(lr + 1, 1, data_clean.length, 8).setValues(data_clean);
  const rangeList = data_data.reduce((ar, [a, ...b], i) => {
    if (!a && b.join("")) {
      ar.push(`DK${i + 4}`);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  srcSheet.getRangeList(rangeList).setValue('SUBMITTED');
}


By this modification, a value SUBMITTED is put into the cells of column "DK" when the cell of column "DK" is empty.

References:

reduce()
getRangeList(a1Notations)


Dear Tanaike. I've tried your modification. It works, but adds SUBMITTED to the whole column rather than just the row, or rows, that were passed to dstSheet.

@manc_stu Thank you for replying. About but adds SUBMITTED to the whole column rather than just the row, or rows, that were passed to dstSheet., I cannot understand the whole column. In my proposed script, for example, when the cells "DK4" and "DK6" are !r[0], SUBMITTED is put into the cells "DK4" and "DK6". Isn't this your expected result? If this is not your expected result, can you provide your actual expected result? I would like to modify my script.

thanks for your reply also. In my example, I have DK4 and DK5 are '!r[0]'. When i run your script, I would expect DK4 and DK5 to show SUBMITTED after the script has finished. Instead, the whole range DK4:DK18 shows SUBMITTED.

@manc_stu Thank you for replying. About When i run your script, I would expect DK4 and DK5 to show SUBMITTED after the script has finished. Instead, the whole range DK4:DK18 shows SUBMITTED., in this case, it is required to know your current situation. Because when I tested my script, I could not replicate your situation. So, can you provide your current script? And also, can you provide your sample value of "DK4:DK18"?

I am using your modified script. Column DK - no values. Columns DL4:DR5 contain values. Therefore when I run the script, it is taking data_range DK4:DR4 and DK5:DR5 to dstSheet. It then adds SUBMITTED to DK4 and DK5 on srcSheet. If I then add more data to DK6:DR6, run the script, it will ignore DK4:DR5 and instead send DK6:DK6 to dstSheet, and populate DK6 on srcSheet with SUBMITTED. Currently, the script you have provided adds SUBMITTED to DK4:D18.

@manc_stu Thank you for replying. From your reply, I modified the script. Please confirm it. In the above modification, even when only one value exists in one row of columns "DL:DR", "SUBMITTED" is put into column "DK". If you want to check that all columns "DL:DR" have the values, please modify if (!a && b.join("")) { to if (!a && b.every(c => c)) {.

Perfect @Tanaike!!! Thank-you very much for taking the time to find solution. Very much appreciated.

@manc_stu Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

You can try this:
function send_purchase_invoices() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");
  var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("purchase_invoices");
  var values = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var data_range = srcSheet.getRange('DK4:DR18');
  var data_data = data_range.getValues();

  var data_clean = data_data.filter(function (r) {
    return !r[0];
  });

  var lr = dstSheet.getLastRow();
  var slr = srcSheet.getLastRow();

  dstSheet.getRange(lr + 1, 1, data_clean.length, 8).setValues(data_clean);

  for (var i = 0; i < data_data.length; i++) {
    if (data_data[i][0] === "" && data_data[i][1] !== "") {
      data_data[i][0] = "SUBMITTED";
    }
  }

  srcSheet.getRange(1, 1, data_data.length, 8).setValues(data_data);
}

Note: The range used in this sample output is for testing purposes only and serves to demonstrate how the code functions.
Sample Output:


Thank-you @Alma-Matters!  This works great also.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
